# Laravel 5 with Heroku: "/" route returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: laravel, heroku, nginx, laravel-5

As the title says, I'm using Heroku with the following Procfile:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C nginx.conf public/
```

After I push to Heroku, I'm getting the following screen:

[image]

Given my experience with Linux, I was sure it has to do something with permissions so I, little by little, tested chmoding 777 on folders recursively, and at some point ended up doing 777 on the entire project, needless to say, it didn't work.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Here's my nginx.conf as per [Laravel 5 docs](http://laravel.com/docs/master/configuration#pretty-urls)

```
location / {
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: Did you check that directory has 755 permission

Comment: which directory? also, does **$ chmod 755 -R /myproject** works on directories too?

Comment: First check if your `/public` and `/storage` directory has proper permissions.

Comment: on **laravel/homestead** vagrant box, **public** directory has **drwxr-xr-x** permissions. **storage** has **drwxr-xr-x**.  I don't know if permissions changes once you push to Heroku, nor I have a way of verifying

Comment: Post your `nginx.conf`, the error is most likely in there. File system permissions are not an issue on Heroku.

Comment: Does the solution work, @ChristopherFrancisco? If so, please accept the answer.

Comment: The problem for me is that i have to add my billing data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `-C` switch, you're overriding the default Nginx config "include snippet", which also contains this:

```
location / {
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

So your problem now is that your rewrites likely work just fine (try a URL like `/foobar`), just not `/`, because the `try_files` directive works (the folder `/` exists), but indexes are not allowed, hence the 403.

The easiest way to fix that is to add an index directive:

```
location / {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

That should do the trick.